# System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'UserPrincipalName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

what is wrong with this query:

```
var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserPrincipalName == "test@company.l");
```

why do I get this exception?

UserPrincipleName is a User property...

```
System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'UserPrincipalName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

When I do this everything is fine:

```
var users = context.Users.ToList();
var user = users.Single(u => u.UserPrincipalName == "test@company.l");
```

Why does the single work for Linq to Objects but not Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a property of IdentityElement the definition is like this:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty(ConfigurationStrings.UserPrincipalName)]
    public UserPrincipalNameElement UserPrincipalName
    {
        get { return (UserPrincipalNameElement)base[ConfigurationStrings.UserPrincipalName]; }
    }
```

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Configuration/IdentityElement.cs,d784c9ed0cd1b486

It returns a string, that's why you can use it with linq to objects, but EF can't translate it to SQL because it gets the value by casting some property in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

`UserPrincipalName` has to be mapped to a column on the database. EF tries to convert the lambda expression `u => u.UserPrincipalName == "test@company.l"` into an sql script and will complain if the `UserPrincipalName` property is not mapped to a table column.

Comment: But still your statement seems not correct to me "UserPrincipalName is of type User" the lambda "u" is the user type and UserPrincipalName is the string property therefore the comparison should not fail!

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the question. Does UserPrincipalName map to a column in the database?